# How to display user-specific content based on which user is logged in

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, authentication

My site has a login feature which only requires a user enter their email. If they're email is in my MySQL database, they are granted access to a private php page (results.php). I'm trying to develop a method of identifying which user is logged in, and depending who it is, display particular content within that page.
I'd like this `results.php` file to dynamically change its content (html) depending which user is logged in/viewing it.

The content within `results.php` is essentially 3`div` columns, with each column containing a list of `a` links in `li` tags that I manually find and add. **Please note:** The amount of list items vary greatly per user. Let's say a user logs in with "hello@example.com". They have submitted keywords to me on a previous page, which allows me to compile a unique list of URLs just for them, like so:

[image]

There could be up to 100 items!

**My question:** How do I display the content (html) that is associated with the user currently logged in? If the unique content consisted only of a few values, I understand you'd simply extract the data from MySQL. But when I'm dealing with potentially lengthy lists of unique URLs, I don't see how to store/extract an entire html file as a variable, or the proper approach. Can you shed some light?

Here's PHP that tries to extract 'html' .. to illustrate my faulty logic:

```
 <?php
       $emailaddress = $_POST["email"];
          session_start();
       $_SESSION["email_address"] = $emailaddress;

        require("common.php"); 
        if(!empty($_POST)) 
        { 
            $query = " 
                SELECT 
                    html 
                FROM users 
                WHERE 
                    email = :email 
            "; 
             $query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $emailaddress
        );
```

and here's a sample of the list items:

```
                   <li>
                       Creative Design, Colorful 
                    <input id="cbox" type="checkbox" name="cbox"  />                  
                   </li>
                     <li>
                       Cheerful People Walking, Bright Sun 
                    <input id="cbox" type="checkbox" name="cbox"  />               
                   </li>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't fetch html from your db but the links and build the HTML?

Comment: Are you saying I should store the URLs into my database? So if I find 80 URLs, I have to manually add them all to my database. And then "build the html". I don't really understand, my apologies.